# What's my ip address on CIDR format for google sql authorisation

Tags: networking, ip, google-cloud-sql, subnet

I'm trying to whitelist my ip address on google cloud SQL storage. However they ask for a CIDR notation. I read the wikipedia page, went through various converters and read some post on stackoverflow on how to convert my IP to a CIDR valid ip. I still can't manage to connect with my ip - while by whitelisting all ips 0.0.0.0 it works - .

So here is an example ip :

```
80.210.10.180
```

if I type into ipconfig I see:

```
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
```

How can I get the cidr ipv4 valid adress ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authorization page will accept plain IPs. e.g. If your IP is 80.210.10.180 you can simply enter 80.210.10.180. (If you're curious, the CIDR notation for this is 80.210.10.180/32, but that's not important.)

If that doesn't work, it's likely that your external IP as seen by Google is different.

Does this IP match what you see if you type "what is my ip" into Google search?

Comment: Yes it does match but, it's weird. Only 0.0.0.0/0 works

Comment: What you can do is connect (with 0.0.0.0 temporarily whitelisted) and run "show processlist;" and see what the "Host" column shows you. See if it doesn't match the IP you are trying to authorize.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I'm following you. I connected through ssh and did netstat -al then I see  foreign address is `*:*` for ssh. Where do you mean I should put the show processlist ? Could you be a bit more detailed as I'm new to this

Comment: Use the "mysql" client to connect to your Cloud SQL MySQL database, e.g. "mysql -h <cloud sql ip> -u <username> -p" After you are connected, you can run "show processlist;" which will show you connection information. From the output, you can see what the server sees as your IP.

Comment: Yup that's it. It was a totally different ip for some reason. thanks

Comment: Sounds like your ISP is doing something funny :)

Comment: @Ced I'm experiencing exactly the same. Do you know the reason of this behaviour?

Comment: Solved too, different IP for server and sql connections... To show your IP in processlist, try sleep(30). Thanks @Vadim